# How can I emulate :shell command in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, terminal, shell

There is no `:shell` command in neovim. 
`:terminal` opens a shell without previous output, while `:shell` contains all the output of the parent shell and all previous shells. Is there any way to emulate `:shell` behavior with `:term`?

Comment: It would be useful to give us more details on your use case and why you want `:shell` instead of `:terminal`. Maybe using `CTRL-z` to put neovim in background and then using `fg` to bring it back would be what you want? [`:h CTRL-Z`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#CTRL-Z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this need of shell integration is to use neovim terminal tab as main shell.

I use also [skywind3000/vim-terminal-help](https://github.com/skywind3000/vim-terminal-help) plugin and `drop` command to open new files in same instance of vim and not in nested ones.

Answer (score 2):

As @statox mentioned, you can use `CTRL-z`. If you want to spawn a new shell from vim, as `:shell` does, you can do: `:!sh`, `:!bash`, `:!zsh` (pick your favourite), which has pretty much the same effect as `:shell`.

Comment: thanks @padawin - but when I enter `:!sh` in nvim I just see "Press ENTER or type command to continue" in the status line, but not the interactive shell I get when entering `:shell` in vim (or also `:!sh`). Any ideas?

Comment: `:!` will not work with interactive commands. The closest you will get to vim's `:shell` is probably using `CTRL-z`.

Comment: How do I get back to neovim after `C-z`?

Comment: @QuaziIrfan RE "get back to neovim:" Depends on your system. If invoking nvim from Bash. In nvim, we press `CTRL-z`, which temporarily stops nvim and returns to the Bash prompt. One way to get back to nvim is to invoke `jobs`, find the jobspec for nvim, then invoke `fg` with the jobspec as the argument to `fg`. See also `man bash` or in [GNU Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to attach to a tmux session from the terminal, i.e. `:term tmux a`. I'm not sure how usable it will be, but it's one way to get a persistent shell from neovim.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

In your **init.lua** you can set **vim.o.shell** to the shell binary you're using in your parent shell.
For bash that's usually /bin/bash & for zsh /bin/zsh.

```
vim.o.shell = '/bin/zsh -i'
```